# Nexus 4 Fails to Boot After Ubuntu Touch Flash

Tags: installation, boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I was running CM 10.2 on my Nexus 4 until I decided to give Ubuntu Touch a try. These are the steps I took.

1. Because I as already running a custom OS, I already has a custom recovery installed (CWM), so I just downloaded the **saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+mako.zip** from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/) and dropped it on to root of my sdcard.
2. Rebooted in to CWM Recovery.
3. Factory Reset/Wipe Cache Partition
4. Install zip from SD and selected the downloaded file.

It said everything was successful, but I'm now stuck on the Google logo after trying to boot. I can get back to the bootloader and in to recovery just fine. I just can't get it to boot.

I loosely followed [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) directions (Manual Download & Installation), I just didn't rename the file - is that truly necessary? As far as I know, it flashes the same way.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Did I need to flash **saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip** first?

Answer (score 1):

After unlocking and rooting, just get the multirom manager app from the app store:

- It makes sure you are rooted, after installing the internal rom I needed to flash SuperSU.zip
- It can update the kernel to one that has the patch
- It will install ubuntu touch and lists all the version for you to choose.

Something I did not intend for is it installs Ubuntu-touch as the main internal rom.

Answer (score 0):

To do a full install of **Ubuntu Touch**, the *phablet-flash* utility will use ..

For **Nexus 7** (grouper)

```
saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip
```

The simplified install log looks like:

```
INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait
INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait complete
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing system to <path>/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
< waiting for device >
erasing 'system'...
sending 'system' (66487 KB)...
writing 'system'...
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing boot to <path>/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
sending 'boot' (7144 KB)...
writing 'boot'...
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing recovery to <path>/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
sending 'recovery' (7172 KB)...
writing 'recovery'...
INFO:phablet-flash:Booting <path>/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
booting...
INFO:phablet-flash:Clearing /data and /cache
INFO:phablet-flash:Pushing <path>/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip to /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
INFO:phablet-flash:Deploying Ubuntu
INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait
INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait complete
INFO:phablet-flash:Installation will complete soon and reboot into Ubuntu
```

---

So, **Yes**.

The *device-specific* file in loaded before the *generic*. However, I'm not sure you did all the steps ..

Try asking on **XDA-Developeres** forum: [Ubuntu Touch > Ubuntu Touch Q&A, Help & Troubleshooting](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2139)